# want to get first word and word starting from pattern '-' from the line

Tags: perl, awk, sed, tcl

I have these lines in my file:

```
getExtractRCMode -engine postRoute -coupled true -effortLevel signoff -qrcCmdType partial
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer {t t t t t t t t t t t}
```

I want the first word unconditionally and only those subsequent words that start with `-`

Expected Output:

```
getExtractRCMode -engine -coupled -effortLevel -qrcCmdType 
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer
```

How will I do it with the help of pattern search and replace?

Comment: An eclectic set of tags.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you mean by `with the help of pattern search and replace` but here's a couple of ways to get the output you want from the input you posted:

```
$ sed 's/ [^-][^ ]*//g' file
getExtractRCMode -engine -coupled -effortLevel -qrcCmdType
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer

$ awk '{printf "%s", $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) printf "%s%s", OFS, $i; print ""}' file
getExtractRCMode -engine -coupled -effortLevel -qrcCmdType
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer

$ awk -F ' [^-][^ ]*' '{$1=$1; gsub(/ +/," ")}1' file
getExtractRCMode -engine -coupled -effortLevel -qrcCmdType
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use perl one liner with regex grouping

```
perl -e 'while (<>){ @ar = m/(^\w+|-\w+)/g; print"@ar\n"; }' file.txt
```

From the command of user [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

```
perl -lne 'print join " ", m/^\w+|-\w+/g;' file.txt
```

Comment: @mklement0 Yaaa.. you are really great. :)

Comment: Improve your regex: `m/^\w+|(?<=\s)-\w+/g` -- use a positive lookbehind to find a space before the hyphen. Otherwise you'll match the "-qux" in "foo -bar baz-qux"

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl (three solutions with basic I/O):

```
set f [open file]
# 1:
while {[chan gets $f line] >= 0} {
    set args [lassign $line word]
    puts [list $word {*}[lmap {a b} $args {
        set a
    }]]
}
chan seek $f 0
# 2:
while {[chan gets $f line] >= 0} {
    set args [lassign $line word]
    puts [list $word {*}[lmap arg $args {
        if {[string match -* $arg]} {
            set arg
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }]]
}
chan seek $f 0
# 3:
while {[chan gets $f line] >= 0} {
    set args [lassign $line word]
    puts [list $word {*}[lmap arg $args {
        if {[string match -* $arg] && ![string is integer $arg]} {
            set arg
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }]]
}
chan close $f
```

The first solution simply picks the 0th, 2nd, ... word in the argument list, which happens to be the ones starting with "-". The second solution looks at each argument and chooses the ones that start with "-". The third solution is an ad-hoc modification of the second that rejects arguments that are negative integers.

The same solutions can be somewhat simplified with `fileutil` from `Tcllib`:

```
package require fileutil

::fileutil::foreachLine line file {
    set args [lassign $line word]
    puts [list $word {*}[lmap {a b} $args {
        set a
    }]]
}
```

Etc.

**ETA**

It goes without saying that solutions like in the other answers can be used in Tcl too, e.g.:

```
::fileutil::foreachLine line file {
    puts [regexp -inline -all {(?:^|-)\w+} $line]
}
```

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm),
[continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm),
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Comment: Thanks for your help. #2 solution is very useful because it choose the one starts with "-".

Comment: getViaGenMode -partial_overlap_threshold -1 -holdFixingCells ClkBuf1 ClkBuf2

Comment: is there anyway to get output like this?

Comment: getViaGenMode -partial_overlap_threshold -holdFixingCells

Comment: Here -1 is the value set by user. So I also want to ignore it. If I use option #1 , then I will get clkbuf2 in the line.

Comment: @Ojas: I've added a third solution pattern that gives this output.

Answer (score 0):

Another Tcl angle would be to treat your data as code, and leverage the `unknown` mechanism. Assumptions:

- you don't have actual procedured named `getExtractRCMode`, etc.
- your options are all in the form `-key value` where you want to see the keys
- printing to stdout is what you want.

```tcl
rename unknown _original_unknown
proc unknown args {
    set cmdname [lindex $args 0]
    array set options [lrange $args 1 end]
    puts [concat $cmdname [array names options]]
}

set data {getExtractRCMode -engine postRoute -coupled true -effortLevel signoff -qrcCmdType partial
getNanoRouteMode -drouteMinimizeLithoEffectOnLayer {t t t t t t t t t t t}}

eval $data
```

prints the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\s-\S+)|\s\S+/\1/g' file
```

Use pattern matching, alternation and back references to achieve the required result i.e. replace the required string by itsself otherwise remove it.